# how to validate either email or mobile in same input field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have coded not empty on fields. how do i check that email is valid or either mobile number is  valid one that too us phone number.

```
if(mob_or_email==""){

                document.getElementById('busp_email').innerHTML="Mobile/Email required";    
                $("#busp_email").removeClass('field_validation_error hidden');
                $("#busp_email").addClass('field_validation_error');
                $("#busi_name").css("color","#f42156");

    }

    if($('#login_password').val()==""){

                document.getElementById('logp_pwd').innerHTML="Password required";  
                $("#logp_pwd").removeClass('field_validation_error hidden');
                $("#logp_pwd").addClass('field_validation_error');
                $("#log_pwd").css("color","#f42156");
    }
```

Comment: Where and how do you set "mob_or_email" variable?

Comment: If you're only interested in HTML5 browsers you can apply a regex pattern to the pattern attribute on the input element, which you might find easier than doing it in JS.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Validate email address in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/validate-email-address-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your request correctly, you may have an e-mail or a phone number in the same field?

You will need regular expressions for this (If my suggestions are not satisfying, search trough the internet, there are many samples for specific cases)

```
function validateEmail(email) {
    var re = /^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$/i;
    return re.test(email);
}
function validatePhone(phone) {
    var re = /^(\([0-9]{3}\) |[0-9]{3}-)[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$/;
    return re.test(phone);
}
```

With these functions you can validate e-mail and us phone numbers.
just use

```
if (validateEmail(mob_or_email) or validatePhone(mob_or_email)) {
  //is either a valid email or (us) phone number
}
```

Comment: Getting error when using SyntaxError: expected expression, got '^'
 

var re = ^(\([0-9]{3}\) |[0-9]{3}-)[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$;

Comment: Sorry, forgot the / at the beginning and the end, edited my post please try with this again

Comment: and also when keying number it should be masked automatiacally